# My correct SQL query (tested on phpmyadmin) is returning wrong result in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Let me explain. I have a simple query which works when I tested it on phpmyadmin but it does not return the right answer in my web application.

This is the function that runs the query:

```
function GetProductsFromCategoryId($categoryId)
{
    global $db;
    $query = '
        SELECT *
        FROM `products`
        WHERE categoryID = 3';
    try {
        $statement = $db->prepare($query);
        //$statement->bindValue(':categoryId', $categoryId);
        $statement->execute();
        $result = $statement->fetch();
        $statement->closeCursor();
        return $result;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        $error_message = $e->getMessage();
        display_db_error($error_message);
    }
}
```

usually categoryID = $categoryID but I hard coded it with "3" because I wanted to see the results. There is whole other database file which handles the connection and I can post them if you want but the other functions work fine. This is a template that I use from Murach's php book ch 24. This function is my own, slightly modified.

With SELECT *, the function should return 2 arrays for for each product as you will see later when I post my result from phpmyadmin. Instead, it only return 1 array for one product.

This is the query I ran in phpmyadmin:

```
SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE categoryID=3;
```

and the result is:

```
        9   3   ludwig  Ludwig 5-piece Drum Set with Cymbals    This product includes a Ludwig 5-piece drum set an...   699.99  30.00   2010-07-30 12:46:40
        10  3   tama    Tama 5-Piece Drum Set with Cymbals  The Tama 5-piece Drum Set is the most affordable T...   799.99  15.00   2010-07-30 13:14:15
```

So, as you can see, it should return 2 array as that is what the fetch() function should do but it only returns one array. I have xdebug set up with netbeans and looking at the variable $result, it has 1 array with productName "Ludwig 5-piece..."

I have been stuck on this for a 3 days and I have zero idea why it does not work. Please please help!

Thanks!!!

PS: Here is the products on table on the database

```
        1   1   strat   Fender Stratocaster The Fender Stratocaster is the electric guitar des...   699.00  30.00   2009-10-30 09:32:40
        2   1   les_paul    Gibson Les Paul This Les Paul guitar offers a carved top and humbu...   1199.00 30.00   2009-12-05 16:33:13
        3   1   sg  Gibson SG   This Gibson SG electric guitar takes the best of t...   2517.00 52.00   2010-02-04 11:04:31
        4   1   fg700s  Yamaha FG700S   The Yamaha FG700S solid top acoustic guitar has th...   489.99  38.00   2010-06-01 11:12:59
        5   1   washburn    Washburn D10S   The Washburn D10S acoustic guitar is superbly craf...   299.00  0.00    2010-07-30 13:58:35
        6   1   rodriguez   Rodriguez Caballero 11  Featuring a carefully chosen, solid Canadian cedar...   415.00  39.00   2010-07-30 14:12:41
        7   2   precision   Fender Precision    The Fender Precision bass guitar delivers the soun...   799.99  30.00   2010-06-01 11:29:35
        8   2   hofner  Hofner Icon With authentic details inspired by the original, t...   499.99  25.00   2010-07-30 14:18:33
        9   3   ludwig  Ludwig 5-piece Drum Set with Cymbals    This product includes a Ludwig 5-piece drum set an...   699.99  30.00   2010-07-30 12:46:40
        10  3   tama    Tama 5-Piece Drum Set with Cymbals  The Tama 5-piece Drum Set is the most affordable T...   799.99  15.00   2010-07-30 13:14:15
```

The first column is the productID and the second column is the categoryID.

Comment: This sounds stupid, but are you definitely connecting to the right database?

Comment: Did you try to remove newlines from you PHP query?

Comment: @Andrey Newlines don't affect the query unless placed inside of a string

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your `$statement->fetch()` only returns a single row from the database. See [`PDOStatement::fetch()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php). I think you want [`PDOStatement::fetchAll()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) instead to return all rows from your query.

Comment: Thanks. I just looked at the other function examples and the author uses fetchAll instead of fetch. I can't believe I miss that. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 7):

PDOStatement::fetch() only returns one row at a time. You must call it iteratively to get the remaining rows.

Comment: Thanks Brian. I upvoted you but Sander has the fetchAll which helps me get this working.